# How to pass a Session to a DataTable?

Tags: asp.net, sql

In my asp project I need to write all Items form the list box into database table using TVP. I have listbox, stored procedure (passing TVP - Table Valued Parameters). The main problem is that passing DataTable is NULL, but the Session isn't. I'll send you my code form aspx.cs file (only one block, if you'll nedd more, let me know).

```
protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //DataTable dts = Session["SelectedOptions"] as DataTable;

    DataTable _dt;
    //_dt = new DataTable("Items");
    _dt = Session["SelectedOptions"] as DataTable;
    _dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    _dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

    foreach (ListEditItem item in lbSelectedOptions.Items)
    {
        DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow();
        dr["Id"] = item.Value;
        dr["Name"] = item.Text;
    }
    SqlConnection con;
    string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
    con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    con.Open();

    using (con)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("TestTVP", con);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter tvpParam = sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testtvp", _dt);
        tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();

}
```

**EDIT**

[Debugging Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivv1U.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding the new rows to the DataTable. You need something like this:

```
foreach (ListEditItem item in lbSelectedOptions.Items)
{
    DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow();
    dr["Id"] = item.Value;
    dr["Name"] = item.Text;

    _dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

A secondary concern is where are you initialising `Session["SelectedOptions"]`? It appears that every time ASPxButton1 is clicked the code will try and add Id and Name columns to it, even if it already contains those two columns. It would seem more logical to do something like:

```
_dt = Session["SelectedOptions"] as DataTable;
if (_dt == null)
{
    _dt = new DataTable("Items");
    _dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    _dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    Session.Add("SelectedOptions", _dt);
}
```

Comment: Thans for your solution, but my main problem still appears. In Session.Add("SelectedOptions", _dt);  - _dt is NULL. What can be the reason? In my earlier code which I posted, was the same. Session wasn't null, it was full with selected items, but DataTable was null. I suppose thas it can't appropriate sesiion to a datatable....

Comment: Have you implemented my secondary bit of code? Just because your Session is not null does not mean that `Session["SelectionOptions"]` is also not null. In my code by the time you get to `Session.Add("SelectedOptions", _dt)` it is impossible for _dt to be null!

Comment: Yes, I implemented the second bit of your code, passed debugging and _dt is null. But Session["SelectionOptions"] - isn't

Comment: I'll show you my debugging scrennshot, but here can't attach the file

Comment: You can paste images in the question.

Comment: Sorry, but can't. As I'm a new user

Comment: The screen shot does not show that _dt is null! it shows that it has no rows in it. Did you hit your break point on `DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow();`. It may be that there are no items in lbSelectedOptions? Also are you getting an error or just not getting the desired behaviour?

Comment: DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow(); works correctly, all the rows which are placed in this listbox are added. No, lbSelectedOptions isn't empty. I have no errors and exceptions, everithing goes fine, but I don't get result I want